# UISearchDisplayController loads images in the wrong way and took 5 sec to access first letter

Tags: ios, search, uisearchbar, parse-platform, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Hello I am having a problem with search. When I want to search for something, it does but the image does not move with the cell. I am using  SDWebImage to display images via URL.  I think that the problem is in string in the code below because both labels display without any problem(cellTitle, cellDescript). And then it takes about 5 secs to access the first letter. Don`t anyone know where the problems are? 
Thank you.

**Before Search**

[image: Before search]

**After Search**

[image: After search]

**And the code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString *uniqueIdentifier = @"colorsCell";

    CustomCell *cell = nil;

    cell = (CustomCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:uniqueIdentifier];


    [cell.imagevieww setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[object objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];


    cell.cellTitle.text = [object objectForKey:@"MestoName"];
    cell.cellDescript.text = [object objectForKey:@"MestoSubname"];


    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"colorsCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
            {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


        if (tableView == self.tableView) {
            cell.cellTitle.text = [object objectForKey:@"MestoName"];
        } else {

            PFUser *obj2 = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Mesta"];
            PFObject *searchedUser = [query getObjectWithId:obj2.objectId];
            NSString *boottext = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"MestoName"];
            cell.cellTitle.text = boottext;

            NSString *bootsubtext = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"MestoSubname"];
            cell.cellDescript.text = bootsubtext;




            NSLog(@"Content: %@", boottext);

        }
            return cell;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed. Only needed to add this line to set up image to good position.

```
NSString *bootimage = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"ImageURL"];
            [cell.imagevieww setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bootimage]];
```